Как испрользовать не поддомены, а каталог?
Я не так сильно знаком с  Caprover, не ругайтесь сильно.
Заметил, что при создании нового приложения всегда создается поддомен, типа app.domain.com.
Можно ли сделать, чтобы приложение находилось по адресу, типа "domain.com/app"
